# Mouse works on and off and makes beep-like sounds...how to fix it?

Tags: mouse

For about four days, my mouse stops working when beep-like sounds start and starts working when the "beep" arises again but now the beeps go on and off but I can't move the cursor with the mouse at all. I'm using the keypad as a mouse. The beep sound doesn't come from the mouse itself but I hear it from the speakers/monitor.

I tried restarting the computer etc. but nothing works. I've been using this Logitech mouse for like 8 years. Is it just a case of "broken"?

Comment: But the thing is I thought I'm only supposed to accept if it helps the problem so it can be useful to others. Most of the answers I got didn't help. Should I "Accept" anyway?

Comment: Set a very specific sound in "sounds" to "Device connect", and "Device disconnect", and "Device failed to connect".  I put some cool voices in there myself, so they are identifiable beeps.  I suspect that the mouse device is disconnecting, there are thousands of reports of mostly USB, and Some PS2 mices in win7 64 bailing out.  Many people switched to PS2 port , and some do not HAVE a PS2 port on the motherboard anymore. :-(  Over at MS forums they supply the usual reinstall and sfc type copy paste to the threads, but not many people reported that fixing it.

Comment: It sounds like you care about doing things right more than M. Xavierjazz thinks.  ☺  How about telling the world *what sort of mouse it is* and how it is connected to your computer?

Comment: one other thing, get it out of the USB3 ports , it doesnt do any good to put a mouse in them anyways :-)  so if you have the new USB3 stuff, put the mouse in the USB2 ports instead.

Comment: It's plugged into USB 2.0.  It's a wired Logitech mouse which has been working fine on the computer for months.  What's the beeping sound about?

Comment: How do I set the sounnds? Um, ya...I'm an amateur. What doesthe beeping usually mean?

Comment: Control Pannel - sound - sounds , in there you can set wave files to specific system event sounds.